# Make a static variable during recursion in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have this code:

```
filtro :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
filtro [] = [] 
filtro (x:xs) 
    | pior x xs = filtro xs
    | otherwise = x : filtro xs
```

I need to make this variable static: pior x **xs** filtro xs .
Any idea how?

Comment: What do you mean by "static"? If you mean it in either the C or the Java sense, then in either case the answer is "you don't, and there's a better way to do whatever you're thinking of".

Comment: Static like keep the variable constant, without changing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to apply `pior` to `x` and the *whole* list, not just the tail. I think some degree of separation of concerns could do you some favors. First off, your function is just `filter`, which can be defined as

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter _ [] = []
filter p (x:xs)
  | p x = x : filter x xs
  | otherwise = filter x xs
```

So we can use that to our advantage. Then

```
filtro :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
filtro xs = filter (\x -> not (pior x xs)) xs
```

Since we make a closure around `xs` when it's the whole list, it'll remain the whole list in that closure for all of time (remember, in Haskell, variables don't change, ever).

If you really want to do it as one recursive function, you'll need an extra argument which remains the whole list for the duration of the computation.

```
filtro' :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
filtro' _ [] = [] 
filtro' xss (x:xs) 
    | pior x xss = filtro xss xs
    | otherwise = x : filtro xss xs

filtro :: [(String, Int, Int)] -> [(String, Int, Int)]
filtro xs = filtro' xs xs
```

In either case, you'll need to store the whole list somewhere, whether it's in an extra parameter or (preferred) transparently in a closure.